# Jumping to another record based on equaling a field value

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have been writing a parts database in Access 2013 creating forms for all my various needs. Each Part has it's own record but now I need to add an "alternate part" field. In other words, if Part 123 is not available, I have listed an alternate item that can be used instead. What I want to do is double click on this alternate part field "Alternate" and have it jump to the record (in the same table) where the PartID field = the Alternate field in the first record I'm not sure if this is a DoCmd type statement or a find statement of some sort. Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Check out DoCmd.FindRecord method.

Comment: I've been trying to get DoCmd.Find Record but I'm not getting the proper syntax to make it work :(

Comment: Edit question to show what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

DoCmd.FindRecord is one approach.

Here is example of another.

```
Private Sub lbxProjects_AfterUpdate()
With Me
.RecordsetClone.FindFirst "ProjRecID=" & .lbxProjects.Column(7)
If Not .RecordsetClone.NoMatch Then
    .Bookmark = Me.RecordsetClone.Bookmark
    .cbxStateNum = Null
    .lbxProjects.Requery
    .Detail.Visible = True
    .cbxName.Requery
    .cbxName.SetFocus
End If
End With
End Sub
```